# Método para crear promedio General

Tags: java, poo, clase, get, set

tengo un proyecto con 2 clases y la primera de ellas la cual es Alumno, siendo esta de aquí a continuación, tiene varios métodos como se puede ver y se encarga de calcular el promedio de un Alumno principalmente, entre otras cosas:

```
public class Alumno {
    
    public String nombre;
    public Float parcial1, parcial2, parcial3;
    
    public Alumno(){
        parcial1= parcial2= parcial3=-1F;
    }
    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }
    public float getCalificacion(float numCal){
        if (numCal == 1){
            numCal=1;      
       
            return numCal;
        }
        else if(numCal == 2){
            numCal=2;
            
            return numCal;
        }
        else if (numCal == 3){
            numCal=3;
            return numCal;
        }
        else{
            return -1F;
        }
    }
    public void setCalificacion(int numCal, float cal){
        if (numCal ==1){
            parcial1=cal;
        }
        else if (numCal == 2){
            parcial2=cal;
        }
        else if (numCal == 3){
            parcial3=cal;
        }
    }
    public float Promedio(){
        return (parcial1+parcial2+parcial3)/3;
    }           
}
```

La segunda clase se llama Grupo y es bastante similar pero la principal diferencia es que tiene que calcular el promedio general del grupo, igual que en la clase de Alumno, puse metodos get y set para asignar y establecer distintos valores, siendo esta de aquí la clase:

```
public class Grupo {
    
    int alumno1, alumno2, alumno3;
    int numAlumno;    
    String nomGrupo;
    
    public String getNomGrupo(){
        this.nomGrupo=nomGrupo;
        return nomGrupo;
    }      
    public String setNomGrupo(){
        this.nomGrupo=nomGrupo;
        return nomGrupo;
    }
    public void setAlumno(int alumno1, int alumno2, int alumno3, int numAlumno){
        if (numAlumno == 1){
            numAlumno=alumno1;
        }
        else if (numAlumno == 2){
            numAlumno=alumno2;
        }
        else if (numAlumno == 3){
            numAlumno=alumno3;
        }
    }          
    public int getAlumno(int numAlumno ){
        if (numAlumno == 1){
            return alumno1;
        }
        else{
            if (numAlumno == 2){
                return alumno2;
            }
            else if (numAlumno == 3){
                return alumno3;
            }
        }
        return 0;
 
    }
    public float PromedioGeneral(){
        
    }   
    
    
}
```

Como se puede ver la ultima parte esta incompleta y es porque es ahí donde surgen mis dudas ¿Cómo voy a calcular el promedio general del grupo si el único objeto relacionado con los promedios, el cual está dentro de la clase alumno, solamente se encarga del promedio de un solo alumno?, se supone que no debo de crear varias variables de tipo promedio, pero en ese caso ¿Cuál es el ingrediente que me falta para poder hacer el promedio general dentro de la clase Grupo?

Voy a incluir la instrucción que me dieron de este ejercicio por si fuera necesaria, el ultimo punto es el que dije con el que tenía duda pero aquí esta por si acaso, tal vez se me esta pasando algún punto pero no logro captar que es:

-Desarrolle en Java la clase Grupo capaz de almacenar hasta tres alumnos con estas características:

**Atributos:**

- Elemento de lista
- Elemento de lista

**Métodos:**

- Uno para establecer el nombre del grupo
- Otro para obtener el nombre del grupo
- Uno más para agregar un alumno al grupo donde se pase como argumentos el número de alumno y el alumno a agregar
- Otro más para obtener un alumno particular del grupo indicando el número de alumno y el alumno a agregar
- Otro para obtener un alumno particular del grupo indicando el número de alumno deseado
- Un ultimo para obtener el promedio general del grupo

Comment: Creas un array o un vector, si tenés n alumnos los incluida en esos y le asignas el método de alumnos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu función `PromedioGeneral()` solo necesita que tengas un array donde tengas todos los alumnos y ya con eso vas sacando el promedio de cada alumno y calculas el total, quedaría tal que así:

```
public float PromedioGeneral(){
    float notaTotal = 0;
    ListIterator<Alumno> iterator = listaAlumnos.listIterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        alumno = iterator.next();
        notaTotal+=alumno.Promedio();
    }
    return notaTotal/listaAlumnos.size();
}
```

Con eso se resolveria tu duda, pero al ver tu codigo y lo que te piden los metodos me he tomado la molestia de rehacertelos de la manera que creo que te los piden. Tal que tu clase Grupo quedaria asi:

```
import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Grupo {

private String nomGrupo;
private ArrayList<Alumno> listaAlumnos = new ArrayList<Alumno>();
private Alumno alumno;

public Grupo(String nomGrupo) {
    this.nomGrupo = nomGrupo;
}

public String getNomGrupo() {
    return nomGrupo;
}

public void setNomGrupo(String nomGrupo) {
    this.nomGrupo = nomGrupo;
}

public void setAlumno(String nombre, int numAlumno) {
    Alumno alumno = new Alumno(nombre, numAlumno);
    listaAlumnos.add(alumno);
}

public Alumno getAlumno(String nombre, int numAlumno) {
    boolean encontrado = false;
    ListIterator<Alumno> iterator = listaAlumnos.listIterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext() && encontrado == false) {
        alumno = iterator.next();
        if(alumno.getNombre()==nombre && alumno.getNumAlumno()==numAlumno)
            encontrado = true;
    }
    return alumno;
}

public Alumno getAlumno( int numAlumno) {
    boolean encontrado = false;
    ListIterator<Alumno> iterator = listaAlumnos.listIterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext() && encontrado == false) {
        alumno = iterator.next();
        if(alumno.getNumAlumno()==numAlumno)
            encontrado = true;
    }
    return alumno;
}

public float PromedioGeneral(){
    float notaTotal = 0;
    ListIterator<Alumno> iterator = listaAlumnos.listIterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        alumno = iterator.next();
        notaTotal+=alumno.Promedio();
    }
    return notaTotal/listaAlumnos.size();
} 
}
```

Y para que todo eso funcionase el contructor de la clase Alumno tendria que ser asi:

```
private String nombre;
private int numAlumno;

public Alumno(String nombre, int numAlumno){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.numAlumno = numAlumno;
}
```

Y una ultima consideración, los atributos de cada clase ponlos siempre en private, no en public, si quieres que otra clase tenga acceso a ellos creas los métodos get y set correspondientes.